# Go net.Conn.Write sending EOF error on TCP Proxy

Tags: go, tcp, packet

## Overview

I'm currently working on a simple TCP proxy to port forward a connection to an echo server that I've placed on a server in my house. I'm running the TCP proxy and client on the same machine, the echo server is the only program on another device.

The client is just a simple python script that declares and initializes a TCP socket and invokes a `socket.send(b'testing some random byte message\n')`

If I direct connect the client to the server, everything works fine but it's when I utilize the client/proxy connection when the server never receives the msg. In fact, the server outputs that the proxy and initiated a connection but only when I try to send a packet through from the client is when the server detects an `io.EOF` error.

### Connections

server listening on : 192.168.1.253:6969

proxy listening on : 0.0.0.0:6969

proxy forwarding to server listener

client connecting on proxy listener

I've reduced the functionality to only have the proxy read and send once, then exit. Please excuse any remaining artifacts...

## Proxy

```
func main() {
    dstDone := make(chan struct{})
    msgChannel := make(chan []byte)

    go func(msgs <-chan []byte) {

        dst, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "192.168.1.253:6969", 750*time.Millisecond)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error connecting to dst -", err)
            os.Exit(2)
        }
        dstWriter := bufio.NewWriter(dst)
        n, err := dstWriter.Write(<-msgs)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error writing to dst -", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Println("Wrote ", n, "B to dst")
        dstDone <- struct{}{}
    }(msgChannel)

    srcListener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":6969")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening for source -", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    srcConnection, err := srcListener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error accepting connection -", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    srcReader := bufio.NewReader(srcConnection)
    msg, merr := srcReader.ReadBytes('\n')
    if merr != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading socket info -", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Message received [", msg, "]")
    fmt.Println("Sending to dst")
    msgChannel <- msg
    <-dstDone

}
```

## Server

```
// Start() is called in another go file's main which only consists of this call and
// initializes a channel for indicating when to quit.

func Start(serverDone *chan struct{}) {
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":6969")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not listen:", err)
        *serverDone <- struct{}{}
    }

    go func(serverDone *chan struct{}) {
        buffer := make([]byte, 4096)
        fmt.Println("-- Server Running --\nEnter 'Q' to quit.")
        for {
            s, err := os.Stdin.Read(buffer)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
                break
            }
            if s > 2 {
                fmt.Printf("Invalid Command\n")
            } else {
                if buffer[0] == 81 {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        *serverDone <- struct{}{}
    }(serverDone)

    for {
        connection, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting connection:", err)
            *serverDone <- struct{}{}
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("%v connected\n", connection.RemoteAddr())
        go customBufferEcho(&connection)
    }
}

func customBufferEcho(connection *net.Conn) {
    defer (*connection).Close()

    inBuffer := make([]byte, 4096)
    outBuffer := make([]byte, 4096)
    for {
        fmt.Println("Waiting for msg...")
        n, err := (*connection).Read(inBuffer[0:]) // tried only 'inBuffer' and did not work
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("Client disconnected") // Server prints this msg on any msg sent from proxy
            return
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading from connection |", err)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("-- MSG Received [ ", n, "B ]--\n", Dump(inBuffer, 4, 4))
        outBuffer = inBuffer

        (*connection).Write(outBuffer[0:n])
    }
}
```

## Wireshark Inspection

[image: Wireshark inspection]

Comment: Because a program terminates when the main function returns, the proxy program can exit before the write at `dstWriter.Write(<-msgs)` completes.   Because the application does not flush the bufio.Writer, there's no guarantee that the data is written to the network connection.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Ah I missed that when copying the code over. I actually have a channel to block main from finishing until the `dstWriter.Write()` completes and still get the same result. Interestingly enough though, if I keep main from finishing by not writing to the channel that allows it to finish, I get the output that the dstWriter wrotes to the socket but the server remains at "Waiting for msg..."

Comment: With that change, the second problem comes into play.  The application does not flush the bufio.Writer.